# Tem como criar uma tabela com Swift que contenha várias colunas?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Preciso montar uma tabela com várias colunas com os detalhes da compra do cliente, mas com a tableView só consigo criar tabelas com uma coluna, tem como usar a tableView ou outra coisa para criar uma tabela com várias colunas? Segue a maneira que preciso apresentar os dados:

[image: Tabela com mais de uma coluna]

Comment: Vc poderia criar uma classe Que herda de UITableViewCell e criar uma célula personalizada, dividindo-a em quantas colunas vc quer. É só imaginar esse exemplo acima sendo a célular com vários labels delimitando espaços, formando colunas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode user uma UICollection, que tem exatamente este comportamento de grid (tipo excel)
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/

Mas aparentemente, no seu caso, uma UITableView, com uma prototype cell, é o suficiente.

Isto porque, o usuário não precisa clicar em um campo distinto, ele provavelmente seleciona a "linha" inteira.

É só arrastar para a prototype cell da sua tabela os UILabels  que você precisa (uma para senha, outro para taxa, valor, etc).

Ela funciona como um template para as linhas da tabela, então você pode criar uma classe customizada que herda de UITableViewCell (como o @Jadson disse nos comentários) para vincular com @IBOutlet, ou acessar via Tags.

Referêcia:
[UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)
[UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html)

Tutorial Prototype Cells:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1