# Como customizar UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift

Estou populando uma `UITableView` com dados que pego em um *WebService* JSON.

Estes dados são textos dos quais eu preciso formatar.

**Esta vindo desta forma:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Minha ViewController:**

```js
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  tableView
//
//  Created by Gabriel Rodrigues on 03/12/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Sephirot. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
  var texto: [String] = []@ IBOutlet weak
  var table: UITableView!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
      self.table.reloadData()
    }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self

    loadPosts()
  }

  func loadPosts() {
    let url = "http://puc.vc/painel/webservice/procedimentosacademicos/"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
      .responseJSON {
        response in

          if
        let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {
          let post = JSON(value)
          for (_, subJson) in post {
            self.texto.append(subJson.stringValue)
          }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
          self.table!.reloadData()
        })
      }
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) - > Int {
    return self.texto.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel ? .text = self.texto[indexPath.row]
    print(self.texto[indexPath.row])
    return cell
  }

}
```

Source de Exemplo: [Github](https://github.com/Gabrielr47/tableView)

1 - Como posso realizar as quebras de linha em textos grandes?

2 - Como posso remover o evento de click nestas linhas? ou indicar uma especifica para ter o click.

3 - Como definir uma fonte customizada para esta `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Você também pode criar uma UITableViewCell personalizada caso queira...

 [Tutorial shrikar.com](http://www.seemuapps.com/tutorial-custom-uitableview-cell/)

 [Tutorial  seemuapps.com](http://shrikar.com/uitableview-and-uitableviewcell-customization-in-swift/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um [pull request no seu repositório](https://github.com/Gabrielr47/tableView/pull/1) com a solução abaixo:

- Ativar `Size Classes` nas views do Storyboard. *Pois assim poderemos trabalhar independente do tamanho da tela do usuário.* [Size Classes Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html)

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

- Setar o `Size` da sua ViewController pro tamanho do `iPhone 5.5-inch`. *Essa é uma dica pra aplicar o design da sua tela usando como referência a tela do iPhone 6+*

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

- Selecione sua TableView e deixe ela do tamanho da view: `414x736`, depois coloque o `Row Height` como 100, por fim adicione os contraints nas margens.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

- O seu arquivo `ViewController.swift` ficará assim: *Expliquei as modificações nos comentários*

```js
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  tableView
//
//  Created by Gabriel Rodrigues on 03/12/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Sephirot. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
  var texto: [String] = []@ IBOutlet weak
  var table: UITableView!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
      self.table.reloadData()
    }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self
    
    // essas propriedades falam pra sua tableView que o tamanho da row será automático mas que o esperado é 100
    table.estimatedRowHeight = 100 
    table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    loadPosts()
  }

  func loadPosts() {
    let url = "http://puc.vc/painel/webservice/procedimentosacademicos/"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
      .responseJSON {
        response in

          if
        let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {
          let post = JSON(value)
          for (_, subJson) in post {
            self.texto.append(subJson.stringValue)
          }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
          self.table!.reloadData()
        })
      }
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) - > Int {
    return self.texto.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {
    
    // agora sua cell será do tipo CustomTableViewCell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    // setando o texto na label textoBasico
    cell.textoBasico.text = self.texto[indexPath.row]
    print(self.texto[indexPath.row])
    return cell
  }

}

// Classe que herda de UITableViewCell para ser sua custom cell
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   @IBOutlet var textoBasico: UILabel!
}
```

---

- Alterar a cell do Storyboard falando o tamanho dela e qual classe ela é.

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

- Por fim ajustar as propriedades da `label` no Storyboard:

  *- Adicionar a label dentro da cell*

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

  *- Setar as contraints da label*

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*- Setar a fonte customizada do texto*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*- Setar as propriedades de linha do label*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*- Conectar a label do storyboard com a label da classe*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**O resultado fica assim na tela**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: +1 excepcional, vi a notificação do github, amanhã pegarei o Mac e farei todos os testes, sua resposta além de me ajudar vai ajudar muita gente por que os detalhes citados podem ser aplicados em várias coisas, questão de size class e aplicar contraints elas estão definidas no projeto principal neste era somente exemplo.

Comment: Duvida, usar tableview e a forma mais recomendada de preencher informações na tela ? Digo isso por que eu vi do web e lá a gente usa table apenas para dados tabulados e section para textos e esses detalhes entende?

Comment: Costuma ser @GabrielRodrigues. Table Views e Collection Views são bastante usados quando se precisa fazer algo desse tipo. Você pode estar olhando o que a [Apple fala a respeito das Table Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ContentViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW3), aliás recomendo você sempre consultar o  [Guia de Interface Humana do iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH66-SW1) pois é um documento que ajuda muito.

Answer (score 1):

Para desabilitar o click de uma célula específica:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

Para mudar a fonte você pode alterar pelo MainStoryBoard, ou via código

```
cell.textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 16)
```

Quebras de linha e número de linhas da mesma forma:

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3
```

Se você tem itens distintos (mais de um texto) para cada cell você pode criar uma prototype cell, como  eu respondi nesta [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98665/27422):

É só arrastar para a prototype cell da sua tabela os UILabels que você precisa (no seu caso texto, título, etc).

Ela funciona como um template para as linhas da tabela, então você pode criar uma classe customizada que herda de UITableViewCell para vincular com @IBOutlet, ou acessar via Tags.

Referêcia:

[UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

[UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html)

Tutorial Prototype Cells:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1

Comment: +1 top, estas configurações devem ser no metodo tableview - > cellForRowAtIndexPath  ? lá que eu insiro o valor na cell. vou fazer uns testes!

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues sim, deve ser no método "cellForRowAtIndexPath"