# Como carregar uma Imagem em uma UITableView?

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

Realizei uma requisição que me retornou alguns textos e umas urls com imagens, estas imagens eu preciso carrega-las juntamente com o texto  em paralelo na tabela.

Estou utilizando Alamofire + AlamofireImage para carregar os textos/Imagens, minha duvida e a seguinte, eu devo realizar o processo de insercao destes elementos na celula da tabela pelo método `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?  por que este evento é disparado quando e iniciado e quando eu percorro pela tabela, com isto as imagens acabam duplicando.

### Exemplo:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
    print("Evento acontece")
    if self.verifyUrl(self.texto[indexPath.row]){

        Alamofire.request(.GET, self.texto[indexPath.row])
            .responseImage { response in

                if let image = response.result.value {
                    let size = CGSize(width: 300.00, height: 130.0)
                    let aspectScaledToFillImage = image.af_imageScaledToSize(size)
                    cell.imageView?.image = aspectScaledToFillImage
                }
        }

    }else{

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.texto[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que alem de mal alinhada fica um texto bem a direita dela, alem disso abaixo e carregado as mesmas imagens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vamos por etapa:**

> eu devo realizar o processo de insercao destes elementos na celula da
>   tabela pelo método `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

A maioria dos lugares em que encontramos códigos sobre `UITableView` usam o método [tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) para preencher os dados da tabela **quando na verdade** este método deveria retorna uma célula reusável o mais rápido possível.

Mas onde devo preencher os dados da minha célula? *Resposta:* No método [tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:) pois como diz a documentação esse método é chamado antes da célula (que já foi criada no `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) ser desenhada e mostrada na tela.

> Estou utilizando Alamofire + AlamofireImage para carregar os
>   textos/Imagens

Para carregar o conteúdo do textos aconselho você usar os métodos iniciais da sua `ViewController` usando um `Array` para guardar o conteúdo retornado dentro do closure do `Alamofire.request` para preencher o seu array e dar um `tableView.reloadData()` assim os dados estariam prontos na hora de formatar a célula.

Quanto as imagens: usando o `AlamofireImage` você carrega as imagens de forma assíncrona usando o método  `af_setImageWithURL(url)`

No final seria mais ou menos assim que ficaria:

```
if self.verifyUrl(self.texto[indexPath.row]){
   cell.imageView?.af_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: self.texto[indexPath.row])!)
   // outras configurações da imagem....
}else{
   cell.textLabel?.text = self.texto[indexPath.row]
}
```

> Repare que alem de mal alinhada fica um texto bem a direita dela, alem
>   disso abaixo e carregado as mesmas imagens.

Isso bem provável(*digamos 99,99%*) é a configuração da sua célula no storyboard especificamente seus `constraints`. Tente dar uma olhada nessa [outra questão aqui do pt.stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101915/como-customizar-uitableview/102200#102200) pois pode te ajudar nessa parte.

Comment: No meu ViewController tem uma fun chamada loadPosts que retorna os jsons, esses jsons eu coloco no array texto. vou fazer os testes mudando para willdisplaycell, quanto ao alinhamento as configurações estão conforme o seu post, até por que foi eu quem fiz a pergunta :)

Comment: Ah é nem tinha visto , os jsons que você fala é o objeto depois do parse do json? Se tiver um desenho de como você quer mais ou menos a cell eu posso te ajudar com os constraints

Comment: Um exemplo da forma que estou carregando: https://github.com/Gabrielr47/tableWithImage

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada e fazer um `pull request` depois.

Comment: Fiz o pull request. Dê uma olhada pois abrange tudo isso que escrevi na resposta.

Comment: Fiz o pull e to testando/Adaptando para a minha necessidade, assim que tiver ok marco como aceita valeu.